# How to increment item on button click Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am working on a demo shopping app. I have a cart component which fetches the cart items from local storage and displays the items in a table. I have given two buttons to the user for adding and removing items from the cart. When the user adds an item to the cart it gets updated in the local storage but does not reflect on the quantity displayed on the table, the quantity updates only when the page is rendered again. **What is the best practice to solve this issue ?**

Below is the code written in Cart.js

```
   render() {
    const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    console.log(cartItems)
    if (cartItems) {
      return (
          <div>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Price per unit</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>
                  <Image src={item.image} height="100px" width="auto"></Image>{" "}
                </td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td><i className="fa fa-inr"></i> {item.price}</td>
                <td>
                  {item.qty}
                  <br>
                  </br>
                  <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(item)} >
                  <i className="fa fa-plus"></i> 
                </button>
                  <button><i className="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <i className="fa fa-inr"></i> {item.qty * item.price}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}

          </tbody>
        </Table>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div align="center">
          <h1>Add Items to your Cart ! ^_^ </h1>
          <br></br>
          <Button onClick={this.routeChange}>Go to Dashboard ! </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: How addToCart function looks like? I think your issue is that the state is not being updated.

Comment: You can create a state variable cartItems and update state along with setting it in local storage.

Comment: I haven't kept anything in state. I am using local storage .

Comment: There's the issue. React needs to know something has updated to trigger a re-render; this is done (normally) via state.

Comment: why using the local storage for this?

Comment: @Shivaraj I am new to React, trying to learn it. Can I implement this using store ?

Comment: You want to use state for this and update the state on each action to see the changes without having to reload. Store you mean redux store?

Comment: okay . yes, redux store

Comment: I tried to explain , using a sample code . Please check the answer. Mostly the things can be handled using states. To start with , you can use state. Once you are comfortable with state , you can surely explore Redux store

Comment: To use store you can either use react-redux library or react context API. You can follow a examples on the doc to get an idea. It’s useful if you have very large application and needs passing of state in multiple levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
 handleSubtractQuantity = (id)=>{
    this.props.subtractQuantity(id);
    this.forceUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can see the state variable for the same like below:

```
 this.state = {
          cartItems: []
        };

    addItem(item){
    this.setState({
      cartItems: [...this.state.cartItems, item]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    export default function Cart {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

    const handleAddition = (item) => {
        if (!cartItems.includes(item)) {
            setCartItems([...cartItems, item]);
         }
    }

    render() {
     return ( 
     cartItems && (
          <div>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Price per unit</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>
                  <Image src={item.image} height="100px" width="auto"></Image>{" "}
                </td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td><i className="fa fa-inr"></i> {item.price}</td>
                <td>
                  {item.qty}
                  <br>
                  </br>
                  <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(item)} >
                  <i className="fa fa-plus"></i> 
                </button>
                  <button><i className="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <i className="fa fa-inr"></i> {item.qty * item.price}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}

          </tbody>
        </Table>
        </div>
      );
    }
)
       <div align="center">
          <h1>Add Items to your Cart ! ^_^ </h1>
           <br></br>
           <Button onClick={this.routeChange}>Go to Dashboard ! </Button>
       </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```